# Accessing a list in Prolog outside of its predicate

Tags: list, scope, prolog

I'm a Prolog newbie working on an assignment that's been giving me tremendous trouble. I have to write a program that solves an *n* by *n* puzzle; the solution's predicate has two parameters, `game(Size, SolList)` where Size is the size of the board and SolList is the solution of the puzzle in the form of a list. Here is the code provided by the professor to generate the board:

```
generate_board(N, Board) :-
  generate_board(N, N, Board), !.

generate_board(0, _, []).
generate_board(1, Columns, [LastRow]) :-
  row(Columns, LastRow).
generate_board(Rows, Columns, [R1|RestOfBoard]) :-
  row(Columns, R1),
  NewRows is Rows - 1,
  generate_board(NewRows, Columns, RestOfBoard).
```

Solving the puzzle requires "clicking" certain squares on the board. What I want to do is generate a list of the squares - for example, when Size = 5, the list would have a length of 25 and go from 0 to 24 - in (if it's possible) the `generate_board/2` predicate. I then want Prolog to remember that list and when using a different predicate to solve the puzzle and present solutions, to register the "clicks" on the necessary elements of my list and output it in the console. I don't know of a way to work around the local nature of lists in Prolog, and so I'm at a loss how to jump this hurdle.

Comment: The common way of "remembering" the list is to pass it around as an argument. You just need a main predicate that will call your `generate_board` to generate the list, then use that list to call your predicate which solves the puzzle. *E.g.*, `do_puzzle :- generate(L), solve(L).`.

Comment: Gahh unfortunately I'm working on an essay right now so I can't try and implement your suggestion for a while, but that makes sense. I do have a `generate_permutations/2` predicate that's partially done (there are several solutions to the puzzle once you get past Size = 2 or 3, I believe, thus the name), so I'll try to puzzle that out (har har) and get `generate_board` in there. I suspect I will have to ask more before the day  is done; I'm still feeling a little lost on this, and I've already gone in to see my prof.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't just pass the list around as has been suggested in the comments, a good way to "remember" it would be by asserting and retracting it.

So for instance:

```
setup_board :-
   generate_board(5, L),
   assert(board(L)).

do_something :-
   retract(board(L)),
   process_board(L, L1),
   assert(board(L1)).
```

You *do* have to be careful with this, though. If `process_board(L, L1)` fails, your board will have been retracted, but no new board will have been asserted.

You can fix this this by using the Prolog "if -> then":

```
do_something :- 
   retract(board(L)),
   (process_board(L, L1) -> assert(board(L1)) ; assert(board(L))).
```

In other words, if `process_board(L, L1)` succeeds, assert the new board, otherwise reassert the old board.